# How to launch stereo view from inside a launch file

Tags: roslaunch, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble with thinking how to do two arguments inside the args type of a node element in the launch file.

Consider wanting to launch the following node inside a launch file:

```
rosrun image_view stereo_view stereo:=/my_stereo_cam image:=image_rect_color
```

We would have something like this:

```
<launch>

 <arg name="stereo" default="multisense_sl/camera"/>
 <arg name="image_view" default="image_rect_color"/>

  <node name="stereo_cam" pkg="image_view" type="stereo_view" args="stereo:=$(arg stereo) image:=$(arg image_view)" >
 </node>
</launch>
```

I have tried different combinations of arguments formats, quotes, and just can't get it to work. I would appreciate any advice.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198508/how-to-launch-stereo-view-from-inside-a-launch-file/) by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2014-11-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use the roslaunch remap tag
http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap

Your launch file should look like this

```
<launch>

 <arg name="stereo" default="multisense_sl/camera"/>
 <arg name="image_view" default="image_rect_color"/>

 <node name="stereo_cam" pkg="image_view" type="stereo_view" >
     <remap from="stereo" to=$(stereo) />
     <remap from="image" to=$(image_view) />
 </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [malvarado](https://answers.ros.org/users/3532/malvarado/) with karma: 80 on 2014-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cataphract](https://answers.ros.org/users/31427/cataphract/) on 2017-09-17**:
This doesn't work, because it appears to be malformed launch file markup. The console error I get is:

```
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token):
```